# Analysis and analyse

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between analysis and analyse?

How can I know where to use analysis and analyse?
Comment with suitable examples. thank you

Comment: *Analyse* is a verb while *Analysis* is a adjective

Comment: Please provide a suitable example. @RexYuan.

Comment: I've analysed your question and find it rather basic, and my analysis also suggests you're new around here. So welcome, first of all. However, I suggest you take the tour and perhaps read the help page to better understand ELL! Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to the ELL :-). Can you please provide more [details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) such as dictionary definitions that you found and/or context where you encountered these words - than we can answer a specific question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you RexYuan. :)
I should take that tour. :)

And last Question please  do answer.


I did told you not to comment here and you did?

Is it appropriate sentence? please comment and Thank you. :)

Comment: @RexYuan -  the/an analysis is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: oh, yeah. sorry for that typo. Did not type what's on my mind

Answer (score 1):

Analysis is a noun.  Analyze is a verb.  Analyse is the British English spelling of analyze.

Analysis can refer to the process of figuring out what is going on.  (Note the article before the noun form of process!)  A report that summarizes what someone figured out can also be called an analysis.

For example:

> Please study what makes StackOverflow such an effective Question & Answer site.  Please analyze:
>
> - Who uses the site?
> - What are good contributions?
> - Who makes good contributions?
> - What features encourage people to make good contributions?
> - What features attract people who will make good contributions?
>
> You have as much time as you want to perform your analysis.
>
> Please write a report about your conclusions.  Hopefully your analysis will be insightful, and easy to understand.

Notice that in the last sentence, it is not clear whether "analysis" refers to the logic of how you analyzed the problem, or to the report you wrote about your conclusions.  It actually refers to both meanings.

Sometimes a report will be structured like this:

> - Introduction
> - Problem Statement
> - Experiment Design
> - Observations
> - Analysis
> - Conclusions

In this context, the Analysis section is a written explanation of:

- what factors the authors thought were important,
- how the authors think those factors affected the observations, and
- what other problems might be affected by the results from this problem.

In other words, the Analysis section is where the authors write down the logic they used to analyze the problem.